# Android TextSwitcher set color

Tags: android

I have a digital watch that works with TextSwitcher. I want to add a choice of color. I added ColorPicker AmbilWarna (works).
problem:
If I choose a color that is set only for seconds. The watch is in the form of H: MM: SS.
After the application is turned off and turned on the color changes for the entire watch.
How do I make immediately sets up the whole?
How to set color for digital clock at once?

```
public View makeView() {
    //for ColorPicker AmbilWarna
    int color = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(BedClock.this).getInt(
                    COLOR_PREFERENCE_KEY, Color.WHITE);
    //****************************************************************
    textView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(
            getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.bedclock_text,
            mSwitchHour, false);
    textView.setTextColor(color);
    return textView;

}
```

Comment: `After the application is turned off and turned on the color changes for the entire watch`. I didn't get it

Comment: Just when i turn off the application and after turn on. Color changed are completely.